# Запрет удаления приложения

Tags: mobile, android, java

Приветствую всех ХешКодеристов :)

Возникла такая задача, что после загрузки приложения на телефон,
удалить его можно только введя свой пароль, который был установлен при первом запуске программы.

Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне возможен случай, описанный [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1231153/807244)

Для этого должна быть установлена ещё одна программа, которая будет отслеживать удалении этой и запрашивать пароль в нужное время. Посмотри в списке установленных нет ли "левых" программ.

Comment: Нет, у меня таких проблем нет! :)

Мне такую вещь нужно реализовать, естественно в добрых целях, против людей, которые воруют телефоны :)

Comment: Ну тогда создавать своё такое приложение, маскировать под какое-либо популярное, и убеждать людей, что для их спокойствия лучше поставить и эту прогу)

Comment: эх, это запарно :)

Comment: Тогда есть второй способ.
1.Пользователь получает root
2.Устанавливает приложение в папку read-only
3.Убирает root
Только вот проблемы во втором пункте. По идее google устанавливает не удаляемые приложения.